# Edit a .jar library?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, .class-file

I've been asking to edit a .jar lib removing all the Log.
I extracted the .class files and from there with a tool i managed to get the .java files.

I guess all i need to do is create a new project in eclipse and copy the .java files, edit and the compile them in a new .jar.

But when i copy the files in eclipse it give me a lot of error due to the build path.
If I compile the .java file with all these aerror the library will work?
[image: Errors]

Comment: Do not delete log statements from libraries. Use the logging configuration to switch off logging is the better alternative.

Comment: It depends on the type of logging (Log4j, commons-logging,...) is used.

Comment: This looks like it is android code? So read up about android logging.

Comment: Can i somehow disable the Log from a library in my code app?

Comment: yes you can.Is there a log boolean being used?Then use Reflection API and toggle the boolean to disable Logging.

Comment: Try to figure out what logging framework is being used using the decompiled classes. Once you've found it, read the doc of this framework or come back here to ask for help.

Comment: you can find any logger properties file in that code.there you can change the properties.