# How can I edit the JAR library?

Tags: android-studio, jar, android-library

I have the library but some class is missing so I want to add a class to Jar library for the android studio, when I open the jar library with [winrar](http://www.win-rar.com/start.html?&L=0) it classes like encrypted and when adding my class to library the program does not detect the class that i added ?? i create the jar file again with [izArc](http://www.izarc.org/) but does not work ??
 i searched a lot but i cant get the answer:

[How can I edit a .jar file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837500/how-can-i-edit-a-jar-file)

[Modifying a file inside a jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224817/modifying-a-file-inside-a-jar)

[Edit a .jar library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28294256/edit-a-jar-library)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add files to a Jar file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239764/how-can-i-add-files-to-a-jar-file)

Comment: yes i know but i have a big library that missing one class and i want to add class but i dont know how to ?